# Android Application for Registration to a website

Tags: android

I have to build an android application. It only have to convey a single purpose. There is a website called www.graffititechnologies.com . I have to create this app to Register to the above mentioned website. I am just a beginner in Android. How could it possible.

Comment: which technology you USE-phonegap/Native????

Answer (score 0):

Create a Web Service on the server of the website! Post the values from the cellphone app to server's Database by calling these web services and passing data through them.

Tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

kindly mark it as the answer if it helped you Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to to use Json to accomplish this task you can upload the php script that registers the user to the website and then you can take inputs from edittext and convert them into string and then send the data to your script take a look at this code..

Sending data:

```
public static void sendData(String name, String emailid, String dob, String password, String lastname)
    {
        String content = "";

        try
        {               
            /* Sends data through a HTTP POST request */
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.graffititechnologies.com/login.php");
            List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", from));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

            /* Reads the server response */
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int chr;
            while ((chr = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append((char) chr);
            }
            content = sb.toString();
            in.close();

            /* If there is a response, display it */
            if (!content.equals(""))
            {
                Log.i("HTTP Response", content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```